# Tomato plant leaves wrong

Tags: tomatoes

I'm new to gardening. Or, rather, I attempt it every year and kill everything by accident. This year I'm attempting tomatoes (I accidentally grew tomatoes when I was trying to compost, so I figured it was a good bet to grow). However, today I noticed that the leaves are all... not right. I just found out I was over watering the poor bugger (my husband said I needed to water it twice a day, so I met him halfway and watered it once a day), but found that's still too much. I read a lot tonight as to what could be causing it, but I fear it's more than one thing. Any help would be appreciated

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: is it getting full sun all day?

Comment: It was. I got concerned it was too much, so I moved it to mostly full sun

Comment: Tomatoes are very sensitive to herbicide ; it can drift hundreds of feet from the point of application.

Comment: I don't use anything... but I bought it at the grocery store.

Comment: Need some more info. How old (big) were they when you got them and how longin the pot? What soil is in the pot or where did you get it? Have you used any fertilizer on the soil? Have you done any pruning of suckers as the plant has grown? Tomatoes should be watered when the soil is beginning to dry, that might be every day if its hot or every 2-3 days. Wait for the soil to be somewhat dry before watering again.

Comment: It hasn't gotten much bigger. I bought it from a grocery store and have only just added fertilizer and some calcium (egg shells) from my reading. I pruned off a bunch of dead leaves the other day when I noticed it wasn't looking great. It's been very hot and humid with one day of hail storm. There's also been frequent thunderstorms--I watered it twice before it rained because the forecast said it was a slim chance... so it got watered twice those days.

Comment: @RebeccaRied Follow my watering advice and make sure your pot has drainage. That's very important. There should be hole of some kind for water to escape the pot. [read here for more tips on drainage](https://www.thespruce.com/watering-and-drainage-in-container-gardens-847774). Let it get used to its new environment for a bit and it may recover. Make sure you are regularly pruning off the "suckers" which are little outshoots at 45 degrees between the main steam and a branch.

Comment: I will check! So, it isn't wilt or that fungal parasite? I was very worried that was the cause.